# Downgrade Nexus 9 running lollipop to KitKat

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat

I'd like to downgrade my Nexus 9 to android 4.X (KitKat). Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: Is it OK if you lose everything on the device? Also I think there might be a better Exchange for this question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using an Android device. It belongs on [android.se].

Comment: Sorry, I was looking for something else and found stackoverflow. I thought that I could ask here. I'm going to post this question there, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is better suited to being asked on https://android.stackexchange.com/questions.

Although, this is how you can do it: http://thetechrism.com/downgrade-lollipop-kitkat-nexus/